# Divide by zero error for some date ranges in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

This WHERE clause works fine for April but when the date range is change to March it returns a "Divide by zero" error.  Both March and April have records.  Any idea how to avoid the error for date ranges?  Thanks.

```
WHERE date_start >= '2018-04-01' AND date_stop < '2018-05-01'
```

Comment: You should show your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily avoid divide-by-zero by using `nullif()`:

```
select a / nullif(b, 0)
```

This returns `NULL` instead of an error.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  I tried the nullif() but it didn't work.  WHERE nullif(date_start, 0) >= '2018-03-01' AND nullif(date_stop, 0) < '2018-04-01'

Comment: After applying the NULLIF() to all divisions as you suggested, the error is gone.  Thank you!  BTW, NULL results still show NULL - is there any way to show a blank instead for numeric types?

Comment: @LeoJones . . . Not really.  Your only option is to convert to a string and represent the `NULL` values as empty strings.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks.